# How to remove uuid from list in config

Tags: java, list, yaml, minecraft

i am making a staffchat plugin and everything but this part works.

It won't remove my uuid from the StaffedPlayerList in config.yml.

Here is the code i'm using to remove me:

```
if(p.isOp() && !Main.getPlugin().getConfig().getStringList("Mai.Staff.StaffedPlayerList").contains(p.getUniqueId().toString()) || p.hasPermission("mai.admin") && !Main.getPlugin().getConfig().getStringList("Mai.Staff.StaffedPlayerList").contains(p.getUniqueId().toString())) {
            Main.getPlugin().getConfig().getStringList("Mai.Staff.StaffedPlayerList").add(p.getUniqueId().toString());
            Main.getPlugin().saveConfig();
        }
        
        else if(!p.isOp() && Main.getPlugin().getConfig().getStringList("Mai.Staff.StaffedPlayerList").contains(p.getUniqueId().toString()) || !p.hasPermission("mai.admin") && Main.getPlugin().getConfig().getStringList("Mai.Staff.StaffedPlayerList").contains(p.getUniqueId().toString())) {
            Main.getPlugin().getConfig().getStringList("Mai.Staff.StaffedPlayerList").remove(p.getUniqueId().toString());
            Main.getPlugin().getConfig().set("Mai.Players." + p.getUniqueId().toString() + ".StaffChat", false);
            Main.getPlugin().saveConfig();
        }
```

Do you see what might be causing the issue?

Here is my config.yml:

```
1353c9f6-e0b3-4311-b46c-9504510ce167:
      StaffChat: false
  Staff:
    StaffedPlayerList:
    - 1353c9f6-e0b3-4311-b46c-9504510ce167
```

Any help is appreciated!